# Block of UI until another JavaScript code fragment finishes using jQuery 

Tags: jquery

I am not using Ajax, but I wanted to display a loading screen until another JavaScript code fragment finishes.
I tried below, but it does not seem to be working.

Any help highly appreciated.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Load Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.blockUI.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function linkHandler(){
                for(i=0;i<2;i++){
                    for(j=0;j<500;j++){
                        document.getElementById("datafield").value=document.getElementById("datafield").value+new Date()+"\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea name="datafield" id="datafield" cols="80" rows="15"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" >Link 1</a><br/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" >Link 2</a><br/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" >Link 3</a><br/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" >Link 4</a><br/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" >Link 5</a><br/>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('a').click(function(event) {
                $.blockUI();
                document.getElementById("datafield").value=document.getElementById("datafield").value+new Date()+" Screen blocked \n";
                linkHandler();
                document.getElementById("datafield").value=document.getElementById("datafield").value+new Date()+" Function over\n";
                   $.unblockUI();
                   document.getElementById("datafield").value=document.getElementById("datafield").value+new Date()+" Screen unblocked \n";
                   return false;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your backend look like.  If you aren't using ajax why don't you just calculate all of these with your php or whatever code?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is, you should remove the uiBlock() inside linkHandler, so that it blocks the user to click on anything or tell them something is being processed.

Note:
Give some interval so that you can see it in action :-).

Take a look at the following code, it works.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Load Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.malsup.com/block/jquery.blockUI.js?v2.38"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function linkHandler(){
    for(j=0;j<5;j++){
        document.getElementById("datafield").value=document.getElementById("datafield").value+new Date()+"\n";
        sleep(100);
    }
    sleep(100);
    $.unblockUI();
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<textarea name="datafield" id="datafield" cols="80" rows="15"></textarea>
<br/>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="$.blockUI();sleep(100);setTimeout('linkHandler()', 500);" >Link 1</a><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps for whatever you are trying to achieve.